# Using jQuery to wrap a slide with a link (Wordpress Revolution Slider plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm using the Revolution slider plugin for wordpress. I have two slides, and I want to wrap the first slide with a link to a Wistia video. This is the code that Wistia provided to me:

```
<a id="topopup" href="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/dw1t2gykvu?popover=false"   
class="wistia-popover[height=360,playerColor=00c5b7,width=640]">Watch Video</a>
<script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/popover-v1.js"> 
</script>
```

I can't add this code to the slide through Revolution slider, so I was going to give jQuery a shot.

This is the structure of the sliders html:

```
<div id="rev_slider_1_1_wrapper">
    <div id="rev_slider_1_1">
    <ul>
       <!-- SLIDE  -->
      <li data-transition="fade">
          <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
          <div class="slotholder"></div></div>
          <!-- LAYERS -->
          <div class="tp-caption sft slidelink hasclicklistener">
            <a target="_self" href="">
                 <div></div>
            </a>

          </div>
      </li>
      <!-- SLIDE  -->
      <li data-transition="fade">
          <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
          <div class="slotholder"></div></div></div></div>
           <!-- LAYERS -->
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Any idea how I can use jQuery to wrap this around the first slide?

```
    <a id="topopup" href="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/dw1t2gykvu?popover=false"   
    class="wistia-popover[height=360,playerColor=00c5b7,width=640]">Watch Video</a>
    <script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/popover-v1.js"> 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:first-child` CSS selector. That script should be included in your header, though.

```
$( "#rev_slider_1_1_wrapper li:first-child" ).wrap( '<a id="topopup" href="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/dw1t2gykvu?popover=false"   
class="wistia-popover[height=360,playerColor=00c5b7,width=640]"></a>' );
```

If you want to include the `Watch Video` text, that's a bit more complicated.

Comment: Remember to change it if you change the order of the slides, using the `:nth-child()` selector